# Passing mysql protocol parameter in local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, local.xml

I have to connect to mysql database specifing the protocol as in this command line:

```
mysql -P port_number -u user -ppassword --protocl=tcp -D database -h hostname
```

Well, port number I think is possible to pass adding ":port_number" to the "hostname" in  tag. User name, database and password have their own tag as in the next example:

```
<connection>
    <host><![CDATA[hostname:port_number]]></host>
    <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
    <dbname><![CDATA[pierpape_reciele]]></dbname>
    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
    <active>1</active>
</connection>
```

What about some other parameter like "protocol"?

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
<protocol><![CDATA[tcp]]></protocol>
```

to the `<connection>` element should work, because in the end, any additional elements gets added to the PDO dsn string, as you can see in `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract::_dsn()`:

```
/**
 * Creates a PDO DSN for the adapter from $this->_config settings.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _dsn()
{
    // baseline of DSN parts
    $dsn = $this->_config;

    // don't pass the username, password, charset, persistent and driver_options in the DSN
    unset($dsn['username']);
    unset($dsn['password']);
    unset($dsn['options']);
    unset($dsn['charset']);
    unset($dsn['persistent']);
    unset($dsn['driver_options']);

    // use all remaining parts in the DSN
    foreach ($dsn as $key => $val) {
        $dsn[$key] = "$key=$val";
    }

    return $this->_pdoType . ':' . implode(';', $dsn);
}
```

It's using a blacklist, to not add configurations that are passed differently but it doesn't restrict any other parameters. So the configuration will result in this dsn, which should work for you:

```
mysql:protocol=tcp;host=hostname:portnumber;dbname=pierpape_reciele
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually Magento calls `Varien_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->_connect()`, here's the code from CE 1.90.

```
protected function _connect()
{
    if ($this->_connection) {
        return;
    }
    if (!extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
        throw new Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception('mysqli extension is not installed');
    }
    // Suppress connection warnings here.
    // Throw an exception instead.
    @$conn = new mysqli();
    if (false===$conn || mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        throw new Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli_Exception(mysqli_connect_errno());
    }

    $conn->init();
    $conn->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
    #$conn->options(MYSQLI_CLIENT_MULTI_QUERIES, true);

    $port = !empty($this->_config['port']) ? $this->_config['port'] : null;
    $socket = !empty($this->_config['unix_socket']) ? $this->_config['unix_socket'] : null;
    // socket specified in host config
    if (strpos($this->_config['host'], '/')!==false) {
        $socket = $this->_config['host'];
        $this->_config['host'] = null;
    } elseif (strpos($this->_config['host'], ':')!==false) {
        list($this->_config['host'], $port) = explode(':', $this->_config['host']);
    }

    #echo "<pre>".print_r($this->_config,1)."</pre>"; die;
    @$conn->real_connect(
        $this->_config['host'],
        $this->_config['username'],
        $this->_config['password'],
        $this->_config['dbname'],
        $port,
        $socket
    );
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        throw new Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli_Exception(mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $this->_connection = $conn;

    /** @link http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18551 */
    $this->_connection->query("SET SQL_MODE=''");
}
```

You can see here the config values that get passed through to `mysqli_real_connect`, the documentation for mysqli_real_connect says
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php#socket

> socket Specifies the socket or named pipe that should be used.
>
> Note: Specifying the socket parameter will not explicitly determine
>   the type of connection to be used when connecting to the MySQL server.
>   How the connection is made to the MySQL database is determined by the
>   host parameter.

and

> host Can be either a host name or an IP address. Passing the NULL
>   value or the string "localhost" to this parameter, the local host is
>   assumed. When possible, pipes will be used instead of the TCP/IP
>   protocol.

So if you want to use named pipes or a socket, you set the host to localhost and put the name in socket.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what about protocol? Ok socket, ok localhost, port etc. but in practice how can I pass the protocol option?

Comment: You can't set the protocol using php_mysqli. It's derived from the other parameters. See the documentation for mysql_real_connect I copied above.

Comment: OP has configured `<type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>` (not `mysqli`), so `Varien_Db_Adapter_Mysqli` is not involved.